How to skip workflow jobs on specific days (e.g., Friday)?
I have a CI/CD pipeline in GitHub Actions that deploys code when changes are pushed to the production branch. However, I want to automate certain maintenance tasks (like cleaning up Docker, temporary files, and performing database backups) on Fridays, during which no deployments should happen. As such, I need to skip the deployment job in the pipeline on Fridays.
Here's my current GitHub Actions workflow configuration for the deployment step:
deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  needs: [pytest] # Deploy only if tests pass
  if: github.ref_name == 'production' && github.event_name == 'push'
  steps:
    - name: Checkout Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Add SSH Key
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: Add known hosts
      run: ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.VM_IP }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

    - name: Deploy to Production Server
      run: |
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.VM_USER }}@${{ secrets.VM_IP }} << 'EOF'
          cd /home/${{ secrets.VM_USER }}/client-portal
          git pull origin production
          git checkout production
          docker compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build
          docker compose -f docker-compose.production.yml down --remove-orphans
          docker compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up -d
        EOF

How can I add a condition to the workflow to skip this deployment step on Fridays or every midnight? I'm looking for a way to prevent deployment jobs from running on Fridays while allowing other days to function as usual. Is there a way to check the current day of the week and apply a condition based on that in GitHub Actions?

What's this triggered by? If it's a schedule, you can tell cron "not Fridays".

create a separate workflow that is triggered on friday

You can try a workaround, like computing the date name yourself, using date %u and $GITHUB_OUTPUT (action linted here):
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production

jobs:
  pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Run Tests
        run: pytest

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [pytest]
    if: github.ref_name == 'production' && github.event_name == 'push'
    steps:
      - name: Get Day of Week
        id: get_day
        shell: bash
        run: |
          DAY_OF_WEEK=$(date +'%u')
          echo "day_of_week=$DAY_OF_WEEK" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Deploy to Production Server
        if: steps.get_day.outputs.day_of_week != '5'
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.VM_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.VM_USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            cd /home/${{ secrets.VM_USER }}/client-portal
            git pull origin production
            git checkout production
            docker compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build
            docker compose -f docker-compose.production.yml down --remove-orphans
            docker compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up -d


As noted by Jon in the comments, if your job can be scheduled, then a simple cron is enough:
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '22 2 * * 0-4,6' # Run at 02:22 AM UTC every day except Friday (5)


Kamil suggests in the comments to create a separate workflow that is triggered on Friday.
Something like:
name: Friday Maintenance Tasks

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '22 2 * * 5' # Run at 02:22 AM UTC every Friday

jobs:
  maintenance:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: production 

      - name: Add SSH Key
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Add known hosts
        run: ssh-keyscan -H ${{ secrets.VM_IP }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

      - name: Clean up Docker
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.VM_USER }}@${{ secrets.VM_IP }} << 'EOF'
            docker system prune -af
            ... # other Docker cleanup commands
          EOF

      - name: Clean up temporary files
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.VM_USER }}@${{ secrets.VM_IP }} << 'EOF'
            rm -rf /tmp/*
            ... # other temporary file cleanup commands
          EOF

      - name: Perform database backup
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.VM_USER }}@${{ secrets.VM_IP }} << 'EOF'
            pg_dump -U postgres mydatabase > backup.sql
            ... # other database backup commands
          EOF

Looking at the GitHub Action Checkout V4 usage, I have added with: ref: production to make sure the action is triggered on the right branch.

Hmmm... This makes sense I will test it out and get back to you. Thanks

will this run only on the production branch? I mean the Friday Maintenance Tasks, if not, how can I enforce that? so that this will avoid all branches from execute the same command at that time

@AdekojoEmmanuel I have edited the answer to address that.
